# Neo4j Protocol Error: Server closed connection

Tags: python, linux, neo4j

I am new to neo4j world. I have successfully used it on my macbook. Now I am deploying it on a remote Linux machine with the same setup. But I keep getting this Protocol error. What caused this issue? How to fix this? I have been banging my head on this error for days.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/knowledge/media_entity_mapper.py", line 31, in <module>
    main()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/knowledge/media_entity_mapper.py", line 28, in main
    map_media_to_entities()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/knowledge/media_entity_mapper.py", line 7, in map_media_to_entities
    data_manager = DataManager()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/knowledge/data_manager/data_manager.py", line 13, in __init__
    self.graphDB = Neo4jManager()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/knowledge/neo4j_manager.py", line 10, in __init__
    self.session = self.driver.session()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/session.py", line 148, in session
    session = Session(self)
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/session.py", line 461, in __init__
    self.connection = connect(driver.host, driver.port, driver.ssl_context, **driver.config)
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 465, in connect
    return Connection(s, der_encoded_server_certificate=der_encoded_server_certificate, **config)
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 237, in __init__
    self.fetch()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 326, in fetch
    self.acknowledge_failure()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 273, in acknowledge_failure
    fetch()
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 311, in fetch
    raw.writelines(self.channel.chunk_reader())
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 169, in chunk_reader
    chunk_header = self._recv(2)
  File "/root/dev/knowledgeGraphH/env/lib/python2.7/site-packages/neo4j/v1/connection.py", line 152, in _recv
    raise ProtocolError("Server closed connection")
neo4j.v1.exceptions.ProtocolError: Server closed connection
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was because I used the wrong credentials for this connection.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be port issue. Is the bolt port open or not? You have access to the port or not?

Check the output of the following command:

```
lsof -i tcp:7687
```

change the port number if you have changed bolt port address.